# $Label.LightningControl.required does not exist

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am getting "$Label.LightningControl.require doesn't exist" over the Tool Tip when setting lightning:input require="true" .

```
 <lightning:input type="text" 
     name="firstName" 
     required="true" 
     aura:id="firstName"
     label="First Name"
     value="{!v.firstName}" 
     messageWhenValueMissing="First name is required" >
```

[image]

Comment: Are you still getting this error? This error seems very weird to me. I tried the same code you have pasted and it seems to work for me. Is there any error in your browser console when you run this code?

Comment: This happens only when i put required = true. I am getting the error even now and i am using google chrome version 58.0.3029.96. Checked with IE as well, i am getting same error.

Comment: Please don't try to beg for help. People will help you if they want to help you.

Comment: @MartinLezer Please learn how to post in a public post. No offence. I too will learn how to post without begging after this. Advice taken :)

Comment: Lol what are you talking about? Here, in this community, it's not allowed to beg for help and to try to make your question more urgent than others. But if you want your questions to be closed, keep trying.

Comment: @MartinLezer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be due to a beta Version Component. Your code is working fine now, I am using Chrome version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit).

ToolTip now displays (please fill out this field)  instead of this 
$Label.LightningControl.require doesn't exist.

Sample code

```
<aura:application>
     <c:TestLightningInputComponent/>
</aura:application>

<aura:component>
<aura:attribute name="firstName" type="String" default="ABCD"/>
<lightning:input type="text" 
                 name="firstName" 
                 required="true" 
                 aura:id="firstName"
                 label="First Name"
                 value="{!v.firstName}" 
                 messageWhenValueMissing="First name is required"/>
</aura:component>
```

Helpful links -  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Please do not leave a signature under your posts; that's just noise and and a link to your profile is automatically added by the system anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<lightning:input type="text" 
     name="firstName" 
     required="true" 
     aura:id="firstName"
     label="First Name"
     value="{!v.firstName}" 
     messageWhenValueMissing="First name is required" />
```

and for more information go to this link : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm

Answer (score 0):

This error seems weird for me too. Are you able to re-produce this ?

I had the same issue in one of my org, but was not able to re-produce again. It occurred only once and disappeared.

It seems that there is some issue in the standard lightning. You got the issue while using **lightning:input** tag. I got this while using **ui:inputSelect and ui:inputText**

Hoping this would be fixed by Salesforce soon.