# Can I use $Label.LightningControl in my components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, customlabel

While reading documentation for the [`lightning:input`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:input/specification) aura component, I noticed that some attributes default to `$Label.LightningControl.activeCapitalized` or `$Label.LightningControl.inactiveCapitalized`.

So what are this `LightningControl` lables? Can I use them in my code, or should I? If yes, where can I this list of LightningControl labels in the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is interesting, Normal syntax of the accesing custom label is 
`$Label.Namespace.LabelName' . So this implies`LightningControl` is an internal namespace used by the lightning team to default a few values here and there.

This namespace reminds me of this error which I faced, a few years back. [$Label.LightningControl.required does not exist](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/178348/label-lightningcontrol-required-does-not-exist/178755#178755)

A custom label should be universally available, I tried accessing it in apex:
`System.debug(System.label.LightningControl.activeCapitalized);` which gave me compile time error.

and in VF as `{!$Label.LightningControl.activeCapitalized}` which again gave me compile time error.

Also what other possible values can there be for this `LightningControl` namespace, 
I tried running this query in Developer Console using tooling Api.

`SELECT ID , Name , Value , namespaceprefix FROM CUSTOMLABEL where namespaceprefix = 'LightningControl'`

This returned zero results, which implies salesforce doesn't want us to use labels in this namespace outside lightning aura components.

**Can I use them in my code?** 
I can confirm you can use them in Lightning Aura components, but not in VF and apex

**Should I use them?**
I would consider them like namespace labels which you get by installing any appexchange package. The thing about them is they are [upgradable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm). So salesforce can upgrade/update the custom lable by putting any patch and it might start breaking your UI /logic. I would not personally use them, unless salesforce explicity documents it.